# PHP Passing Ajax with Variable, returning with different one

Tags: php, ajax, variables, return

I'm building a simplified referral system.

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    document.getElementById("getref").onclick = function setref() {
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'newref.php', // the script to call to get data
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',  // data format  
            data: {ip:<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?>},                        
            // you can insert url arguments here to pass to api.php
            // for example "id=5&parent=6"    
            success: function(data) // on receive of reply
            {
                alert('returned ' + data); //get id
                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                // 3) Update html content
                //--------------------------------------------------------------
                $('#bottom_msg').html("<b>freegoldtrial.com/"+id+"</b>");
                // Set output element html
                // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Inside newref.php

```
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
$key = substr(md5(microtime()),rand(0,26),5);
include DB.php

if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("database", $conn);
$tbl_name = "refs";
$sql="INSERT INTO refs(ip, id) VALUES ('".$ip."','".$key."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con)
```

How do I return the generated $key variable to the index? As you can see, I'm trying to replace div contents with it. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: `echo $key` ..?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just add the line

```
echo $key;
```

to the end of your php file. Then the *data* variable in the success method contains its value. 
As mentioned in some of the comments already, this code has some weaknesses which you should cover before actually putting it live.